# Hive : How to convert string to array of arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hive, hiveql

I have a hive column value stored as string

```
[[1,2],[3,4,8],[5,6,7,9]]
```

I need to find out the length of each inner array. How should i go about it ?

Basically i need a query that sums up the sizes of each inner array. Had this column been stored as an array of arrays, i would do something like this

```
select sum(size(innerArray)) from myTab lateral view explode (mycol) arr as innerArray;
```

but now when i try the above, i get

```
FAILED: UDFArgumentException explode() takes an array or a map as a parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your initial array is not real array, it is string, you need to parse and explode it:

```
with mytable as(
select '[[1,2],[3,4,8],[5,6,7,9]]' as mycol
)

select mycol as original_string,
       innerArray_str, 
       --split inner array and get size
       size(split(innerArray_str,',')) inner_array_size
from mytable
    --explode upper array
    --replace `],` (allow spaces before comma) with `,,,` and remove all `[` and `]`, split using ,,, as a delimiter 
     lateral view outer explode(split(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(mycol,'\\] *,',',,,'),'\\[|\\]',''),',,,') )e as innerArray_str
```

Result:

```
original_string             innerarray_str  inner_array_size
[[1,2],[3,4,8],[5,6,7,9]]   1,2             2
[[1,2],[3,4,8],[5,6,7,9]]   3,4,8           3
[[1,2],[3,4,8],[5,6,7,9]]   5,6,7,9         4
```

Now you can add `sum()` and `group by`.